# BatchUpdate on identity columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc, prepared-statement

Assuming I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProposalDetails](
 [ProposalId] Numeric(15,0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [ProjectProposalId] Numeric(15,0) NOT NULL,
 [projectId] Numeric(15,0) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [ProposalDetails$ProposalId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

An attempt to insert multiple records as batch in the following manner - (no inserts on identity column):

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO ProposalDetails"
                + "(ProjectProposalId,projectId) VALUES"
                + "(?,?)";
        preparedStatement= conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);//commit trasaction manually

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
            preparedStatement.setInt(1,...);
            preparedStatement.setString(2,...);
           preparedStatement.addBatch();
        }
        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
        conn.commit();
```

This leads to the following exception:

a.sql.BatchUpdateException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint '...'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ProposalDetails'. The duplicate key value is (1).

Does batchupdate not work for IDENTITY columns?
I am on SqlServer 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Since your PK is the ProposalId column alone and identity can be handling it by itself there's something you are missing.

1) Check if there are triggers trying to insert bad values in that table.

2) Verify if any coworker left a the table with set identity_insert ON.

3) Check if there are another schema (other than dbo) with another table named ProposalDetails but slight different columns.

4) You can use reseed to put the tables back on trails.
http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms176057.aspx